# I want to define a validation for my field in yii

Tags: validation, yii, pattern-matching

I want to define a validation for my field :
All numbers **except zero and two**
can I define my pattern?
what means $ and U ,p and other character?

```
'pattern'=>'/^[\p{L}\s,0-9]+$/u'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In model add code

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
            array('field_name','match', 'pattern'=>'/^[^02]+$/u','message'=>'Invalid Number.'),
    );
}
```

Comment: @Gaidhane it apply 0 and 2, i want to be except 2 and 0 what means \p or {L} and \s and []????

Comment: check out this array('field_name','match', 'pattern'=>'/^[^02]+$/u','message'=>'Invalid Number.'),

Comment: for your other queries go through this site http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node79.html

Comment: your response was very useful for me but i can not vote up because my reputation is down than 15 but i accepted your answer i had a user in stackoveflow by lot of  reputation but stackoverflow ban me!!!! i donot why? and what What should I do? can help me? my id is masoudy.maryam@gmail.com

Comment: can u explain me what means ^ out of beraket[] and ^ in to beraket? how can define length for pattern? sample validation is All numbers except zero and two by fix 10 number

Comment: ooooooooooo your answer was good and useful but not enough  for me  my reputation is down i can not vote up !!!!!!

Comment: Hey refer [this link](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node79.html) it is useful, it will solve your all queries

Answer (score 1):

An overly complex regular expression won't do you any good. Instead, take advantage of the [`not`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CRegularExpressionValidator#not-detail) setting, which is effectively inverting the pattern for you:

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('field_name','pattern'=>'/^[02]$/','not'=>true),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you do it using your model rule

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
                   // your other rules
        array('fieldName', 'patternCheck'),
    );
}

public function patterCheck($attribute, $params){
    $pattern = '/^[\p{L}\s,0-9]+$/u';
    preg_match($pattern, $attribute->fieldName, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    return $matches;
}
```

This will validate your field

Comment: it apply 0 and 2, i want to be except 2 and 0 what means \p or {L} and \s and []????